# Run terminal code from a website

Tags: command-line, apache2

How could I execute a line of terminal code, like this

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

from the press of a button on a website hosted on the same machine (with `apache`).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question right. You want a terminal window that shows some text when someone clicks on a button on website?

Comment: Basicly, for example, when a button (for example) is pressed on a website, run a terminal command to start a server. Sorry for my bad question writing ... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* achieve this in several ways:

1. Write a CGI script which gets run when you visit a certain web page. The CGI script would then start the shell command. Read up on CGI in the Apache httpd documentation.
2. Put a PHP page on your server, and in that page put a `system()` call executing the program you wish to execute. Any PHP tutorial will show you how to do this.

However, if you intend put this page on the public internet, you can be quite sure this will be abused.  For one, make sure the program can only start once or your server will be on its knees on day 1.

Comment: "you can be quite sure this will be abused"...

Comment: yeah this is just for a local web server. Thanks for your concern though :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to create a minecraft server.

While it is possible to control your minecraft-server by webpage, this isn't the easy way to go. 'Traditionally' you would like to it by a ssh console. You can set it up by following these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html).

If you are also struggling to setup your minecraft server, you might also find this [minecraft start-up script](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Ubuntu_startup_script) helpful.

Comment: haha thanks for the great answer, but I was only using minecraft as an example. By the way, I just wanted to let you (MadMike) that you style of answering questions makes me as a noob feel alot, well, less noob. Thanks :)